# Dropdownlist php doesn't show data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code for populating data into `dropdown` list from **mysql** database

```
<select name="robes">
  <?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM robes ORDER BY Classement ASC")or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $color = $row["color"];
    ?>
    <option value="<? echo $row['Id_robe']; ?>"><? echo $color;?></option>
    <?php
  }?>
</select>
```

now my problem that there is *no data shown* and *no error message* also.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: Have you looked at your PHP Error Log?

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the advice, actually I'm studing pdo connection but I just need this for a specific thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check if php short tag is enabled?
Or Use full php tag like

```
<?php instead of <?
```

Comment: Better suggest they use `<?php` as that will always work

Comment: now I need help in another thing If I want to show dropdown list for editing to update the form I want it to show with the selected value how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First check `Short tag` open or not in `php.ini` if not then  `SET`

```
short_open_tag=On
```

but better is to use

```
 <select name="robes">

        <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM robes ORDER BY Classement ASC")or die(mysql_error()); 

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['Id_robe'];?>"><?php echo $row["color"];?></option>

        <?php
        } 
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.